# Which method of creating threads is better?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: “implements Runnable” vs. “extends Thread”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

When should you use:

```
    class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Important job running in MyThread");
    }

    public void run(String s) {
        System.out.println("String in run is " + s);
    }
}
```

over:

```
    class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Important job running in MyRunnable");
    }
}
```

Obviously we instantiate these differently but is there any difference once they are created?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/541506/597657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread` is a class that implements `Runnable` interface. Essentially, that means that this is allowable:

```
Runnable runnable = new MyThread();
runnable.run();
```

By implementing a `Runnable`, you're essentially have to implement the `run()` method for the Thread to execute it.

Other than that, I don't know what you're really asking.

Comment: -1, [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) is not an abstract class and your example code is really confusing (`run()` vs. `start()`).

Comment: Sorry, I did edit my post...and no....`Runnable` class has only the `run()` method.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman `Runnable` is not a class :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, I didn't say that `Runnable` is a class. I said that `Thread` is a class that **implements** `Runnable`. Read properly. :-)

Comment: `Runnable class has only the run() method` ;)

Comment: Ooops...I can't re-edit my comment....just a mistake.